# GWT (Cell Widgets): CheckBoxes with Labels in CellList

Tags: gwt, widget

I want to build a CheckBox List like...

```
|===========| 
| x label0  | 
| x label1  | 
| x label2  | 
|===========|
```

...using CellList and I've done the following:

```
final List<Boolean> checks = Arrays.asList(true, false, true,  true, false); 

final CheckboxCell checkboxCell = new CheckboxCell(); 
final CellList<Boolean> checkBoxCellList = new CellList<Boolean(checkboxCell); 
checkBoxCellList.setRowData(checks);
```

...so I get:

```
|=======| 
| x     | 
| x     | 
| x     | 
|=======|
```

But how can I supply not only the value of a CheckBox (Boolean) but also its 
label like it's possible with

```
CheckBox#setText("label0")

CheckBox#setValue(true)
```

?

Answer (score 3):

I have done a similar thing for CellTable. So maybe **SOMETHING** like this will work. You need to provide your own render() method. So in the render() method below, you can add whatever you want.

```
Column<MyJSONObject, String> selectCheckBoxColumn =
                new Column<MyJSONObject, String>(new MyCheckBoxCell()) {

                   @Override
                   public String getValue(MyJSONObject object) {
                      return object.getInternalId() + SEPERATOR +  "true";
                   }
                };
             MyCellTable.addColumn(selectCheckBoxColumn, "Display title");

    .....
    .....
    .....

       private class MyCheckBoxCell extends AbstractCell<String> {

          @Override
          public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {


             // ##############################################
             String[] values = value.split(SEPERATOR);        
             // NOW values[0] contains the string value
             // AND values[1] contains the boolean value
             // ##############################################

             sb.appendHtmlConstant("<input type='checkbox' name='" + htmlDOMId1 + "'" +
                                   " id='" + htmlDOMId1 + "'" +
                                   " value='" + value + "'" +
                                   "></input>");

          }
       }
```

Comment: That's basically what I've tried too but I thought there is an out-of-the-box solution. However I can't supply my MyCheckBoxCell with both, a boolean value AND a string name and passing it to checkBoxCellList because checkBoxCellList accepts only a list with just a single type of parameters.

Comment: @Alexander Orlov You can do that. So in your getValue() function, just return a concatenated string containing both the boolean and a string values. Then in your render method, parse the string and get back both the boolean and the string value. I have edited my answer above.

Comment: Thx, however I think using plain CheckBoxes is architecture-wise the better solution at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I've just done this, so thought I would provide an answer anyway.

A `CellList` can only hold a vertical list of a single cell type. If you want to have a `Checkbox` in there, along with some other data, you need to build a custom cell and extend `CompositeCell`, which will combine and render multiple cells inside a single cell. [You can see this in action here in the GWT Showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree) (the innermost cell in the `CellTree`).

So your code should look something like this:

```java
        // first make a list of HasCell type - MyClass is the type of object being displayed in the CellList (could be String for simple labels)
        List<HasCell<MyClass, ?>> hasCells = new ArrayList<HasCell<MyClass, ?>>();

        // then add your checkbox cell to it
        hasCells.add(new HasCell<MyClass, Boolean>()
        {
            private CheckboxCell cell = new CheckboxCell(true, false);

            public Cell<Boolean> getCell()
            {
                return cell;
            }
            public FieldUpdater<MyClass, Boolean> getFieldUpdater()
            {
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            public Boolean getValue(MyClass object)
            {
                return selectionModel.isSelected(object);
            }
        });

        // then add your TextCell
        hasCells.add(new HasCell<MyClass, MyClass>()
        {
            private TextCell cell = new TextCell(myString);

            @Override
            public Cell<MyClass> getCell()
            {
                return cell;
            }
            public FieldUpdater<MyClass, MyClass> getFieldUpdater()
            {
                return null;
            }
            public MyClass getValue(MyClass object)
            {
                return object;
            }
        });

        // now construct the actual composite cell using the list (hasCells)
        Cell<MyClass> myClassCell = new CompositeCell<MyClass>(hasCells)
        {
            @Override
            public void render(Context context, MyClass value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
            {
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<table><tbody><tr>");
                super.render(context, value, sb);
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("</tr></tbody></table>");
            }
            @Override
            protected Element getContainerElement(Element parent)
            {
                // Return the first TR element in the table.
                return parent.getFirstChildElement().getFirstChildElement().getFirstChildElement();
            }
            @Override
            protected <X> void render(Context context, MyClass value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb, HasCell<MyClass, X> hasCell)
            {
                // this renders each of the cells inside the composite cell in a new table cell
                Cell<X> cell = hasCell.getCell();
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("<td>");
                cell.render(context, hasCell.getValue(value), sb);
                sb.appendHtmlConstant("</td>");
            }
        };

        // then make the actual cellList, passing the composite cell
        myList = new CellList<MyClass>(myClassCell);
        // add selectionModel, making sure to pass in a checkBoxManager as a second parameter, or the selectionModel will not work
        myList.setSelectionModel(selectionModel, DefaultSelectionEventManager.<MyClass> createCheckboxManager());

        // construct a dataProvider for dynamic editing of the list (alternative to list.setRowData())
        dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<MyClass>(data);
        // associate the dataProvider with the CellList
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(myList);
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to use a CellTable and dont add column headings (so it looks like a CellList)

Have a column for the checkbox (using CheckBoxCell) and have a column for your other data.
This is the cleanest way. No mucking around with your own custom cells with html-checkboxes inside of them.

This also works well with things like having a MultiSelectionModel on the cell table to get the values of the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

A GWT book I'm reading has an example of this, except the author uses a vertical panel with checkboxes in the panel. With a little styling, you have a listbox look

Comment: And what would be the book's title?